# Update jar file in Solr 4.4.0

Tags: solr, cloud, apache-zookeeper

I have Solr cloud configuration which we run on 4 servers. We use tomcat as web server for solr. I have 5 zookeepers to maintain the data-replication. I have added a jar file with custom update processor. This is in shared folder which is mention in solr.xml

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="/solr/lib">
```

While creating the first version of this jar file I gave the name updateProcessor.0.1.jar as the file name. Even though it was shared, jar files were added in all the 4 servers.

But now I have to update the updateProcessor. For this I created updateProcessor0.2.jar. I deleted the updateProcessor.0.1.jar from each sever and added a new one. But changes were not seen ?

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Should this is be checked using zkcli ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a roundabout which may help someone in future maybe.

I changed entry in solrconfig from

```
<processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.MyUpdateProcessorFactory">
```

to

```
<processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.MyUpdateProcessorFactory2">
```

I renamed the class file I created in solr config from **MyUpdateProcessorFactory** to **MyUpdateProcessorFactory2**